# How can I have different file for development and deployment using webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have some config files which basically stores some data.
However, I am using different data for development and deployment.

I don't want to manually change the file whenever I try to deploy it. Nor do I want to change the import statement before deployment.

for example. I have some code

```
import './config/data.js'
```

I don't want to modify this. I only want the content of `data.js` to change between development and deployment.

How can I setup webpack to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The way I am achieving this is to have different version of this file like `dev.js`, `stag.js`, `prod.js` and etc.

Then I tell webpack to copy the right file and rename it to `config.js` using the `CopyPlugin`

```
 var argv = require('yargs').argv;
 var ENV = argv.env;

 new CopyPlugin([
    {
        from: path.join(__dirname, 'config/properties/' + ENV + '.js'),
        to: '<path-to-config-file>/config.js'
    }
];
```

Then I run `webpack --env=dev` and webpack does all the magic.